# producer consumer program in c - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

Hi I am bit new to C programming. Facing problem with producer consumer problem. When ever I try running the below code i get segmentation fault (core dumped). Please suggest where I am going wrong. But this code works for one consumer but for multiple consumer it is throwing error.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAXNITEMS       20
#define MAXNTHREADS     5
void *produce(void *arg);
void *consume(void *arg);
/* globals shared by threads */
int     nitems=MAXNITEMS;     /* read-only by producer and consumer */
int     buff[MAXNITEMS];
int     Nsignals;

struct {
    pthread_mutex_t       mutex;
    int buff[MAXNITEMS];
    int       nput;   /* next index to store */
    int       nval;   /* next value to store */
} put = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER }; 
/** struct put is used by producer only ***/
struct{
    pthread_mutex_t    mutex;
    pthread_cond_t     cond;
    int                 nready;  /* number ready for consumer */
} nready = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,0};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int       i, prod, con;
    pthread_t tid_produce[MAXNTHREADS],  tid_consume[MAXNTHREADS];
    printf("Enter the number of producers : \n");
    scanf("%d",&prod);
    printf("Enter the number of consumers: \n");
    scanf("%d",&con);
    /* create all producers and consumers */
    for (i = 0; i < prod; i++) 
    {
        printf("1 %d\n", i);
        pthread_create(&tid_produce[i], NULL,produce, NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < con; i++) {
        printf("2 %d\n", i);
        pthread_create(&tid_consume[i], NULL, consume, NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < prod; i++) {
        printf("3 %d\n", i);
        pthread_join(tid_produce[i], NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < con; i++) {
        printf("4 %d\n", i);
        pthread_join(tid_consume[i], NULL);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *produce(void *arg)
{
    for ( ; ; ) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&put.mutex);
        if (put.nput >= nitems) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&put.mutex);
            return(NULL); /* array is full, we're done */
        }
        put.buff[put.nput] = put.nval;
        printf ("producer %lu produced :%d \n",pthread_self(), put.buff[put.nput]);
        put.nput++;
        put.nval++;
        printf("outside producer lock\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&put.mutex);
        *((int *) arg) += 1;
    }
}

void *consume(void *arg)
{
    int       i;
    for (i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&nready.mutex);
        while (nready.nready == 0){
            pthread_cond_wait(&nready.cond,&nready.mutex);
        }
        printf ("consumer %lu consumed %d \n", pthread_self(),nready.nready);
        nready.nready--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&nready.mutex);

        if (buff[i] != i)
            printf("buff[%d] = %d\n", i, buff[i]);
    }
    return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: when defining a `struct`, always include a `tag name` as that is what most debuggers use to be able to list the individual fields within the struct

Comment: @user3629249 It does compile. However, you're still right that the code is quite hard to read.

Comment: this line: `struct`  should be: `struct structTag`   this line: `} put = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER };` should be more like: `};  struct structTag put { .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER };`  Similar considerations should be applied to the `struct nready`

Comment: @klutt,  No, it does not compile, here are some of the problems:  ...warning: missing initializer for field 'buff' of 'struct <anonymous>'  and in the `main() function: ...warning: unused parameter 'argc' and ...warning: unused parameter 'argv'  in the `consume()` function: ...warning: unused parameter 'arg'   When asking a question about a runtime problem, the posted code must cleanly compile.

Comment: @user3629249 The likelihood of a mistake from me causing a non-compiling piece code to compile while just copy-pasting it into an editor must be the smallest positive number that exists.

Comment: So when you're saying "it does not compile", what you actually mean is "it does not compile *without warnings*"?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Whether it compiles cleanly or not depends on which compiler you're using and which options you use.  Since the OP should be using fussy options so the compiler identifies as many problems as possible, it is not wholly unreasonable to say "it does not compile under baseline options such as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror …`".  Compiling with anything less is not really sensible; there are too many mistakes that you can make that will be spotted by those options.  Personally, I require more stringent options than that — though the difference in result is small.

Comment: @klutt,  of course, code with warnings cannot be trusted Suggest, if your using `gcc` or similar that you have the option: `-Werror`

Comment: The code doesn't check that input values for `prod` and `con` are sane.  If the number is less than 1 or greater than MAXNTHREADS, you should report an error (and probably exit).

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care) 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}',  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when not using a passed parameter, like in the `consume()` function, the first line of the body of the function should be similar to: `(void)arg;`

Comment: I'm not arguing against using flags like -Wall, -Wextra and -Werror. Using them is very sensible. I'm arguing against saying that it doesn't compile when it clearly does. It's certainly not obvious what you mean. Anyone who would think it was obvious would already be using those flags and acting on warnings.

Comment: @user3629249 sorry for the mis representation of the code(thought to shrink the size of the code so tried removing the spaces). Next time i will keep this in mind. And the code compiles without any warning for me.

Comment: @klutt,  I agree that a programmer would be using those flags and would fix the compile problems BEFORE posting the code on stackoverflow.com (unless their question is based on not knowing how to fix the problems.)

Comment: @PreethamWILFREDJOHN,  strongly suggest you modify your compile statement to enable all the warnings ( for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: user3629249 sure will try that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*((int *) arg) += 1` inside `produce(...)` causes the `segmentation fault`. Because `pthread_create(&tid_produce[i], NULL,produce, NULL);` passes `NULL` as `arg`.

So we need to allocate some memory for `arg`.

```
// main
int i, prod, con;
pthread_t tid_produce[MAXNTHREADS],  tid_consume[MAXNTHREADS];
int p_arg[MAXNTHREADS]; // <======
// ...
for (i = 0; i < prod; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&tid_produce[i], NULL,produce, p_arg+i); // <====
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the `p_narg` array.